# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a temperature gradient on a map of the Gulf of Mexico using matplotlib. I defined lat,long,and temp as x,y,z. Ideally I'd like to have points for each coordinate plotted on top of a map with a colored temperature gradient. Here is the code I used (I shortened the data sets for simplicity):

```
poslat=[29.50736,24.50824,28.99417,27.0074,27.00416,26.51342,26.00732,25.99168,26.49908]
poslon=[-86.50889,-84.49289,-87.00188,-89.99935,-91.00347,-90.99752,-91.50267,-92.00522]
postemp = [24.73,24.753,24.753,24.756,24.778,24.859,24.859,24.859,24.867,24.867,24.867,25.224]
x,y,z=m(poslon,poslat,postemp)
m.plot(x,y,'ro',markersize=5)
plt.contour(x,y,z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()`
```

and here are the errors I am getting:

```
    Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/sydneyharned/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 1711
    if limb is not ax.axesPatch:
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The axesPatch function was deprecated in version 2.1. Use Axes.patch instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sydneyharned/praccompproject.py", line 31, in <module>
    x,y,z=m(poslon,poslat,postemp)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I can't seem to figure out values I'm missing.. does anyone know how to fix either of these? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without the `m`?

Comment: it looks like m is an alias for matplotlib.pyplot. so why x,y,z=m(poslon,poslat,postemp)? you can just `x,y,z=(poslon,poslat,postemp)`

Comment: function 'm' seems to be the issue here. Check the return statement on that

Comment: The basemap maps 2D coordinates, not 3D coodinates. It would not make sense to map temperature as coordinates, right? So you need `x,y=m(poslon,poslat)`. Once that is done you will run into another problem, which we cannot solve for you: You have only a list of coordinates, but `contour` requires a grid. So you need to see for yourself what you actually want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You should check return of function "m".

As debug info describes, "m" returns only two value, while in the usage of it, it needs three.

```
(x,y,z) = m(poslon,poslat,postemp)

# should return (x,y) maybe
```